# How to change cell range without deleting it?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

In a function, let's say the SUM function, I have a range **H25:H37** I want to change this range to **H23:H40** using the mouse. The only way I could find is to delete the initial value, then I can drag the mouse to select the new value. Is there a shortcut or some keyboard trick that allows me to change the range without deleting it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- try **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`H`</kbd>**
- select specific range if its only in one cell
- and also select within formulas

  [image: 0]

Comment: You're missing the point.  The user is looking for behavior that mimics excel, where when editing a formula, if you select a cell address or range in the formula bar, you can immeduately select a different cell or range in the sheet  using the mouse and the formula will update to reflect the selection.  In sheets the same behavior will cause you to exit editing the cell and the cell will not update.  Workaround is to delete the cell ref or range & only then will clicking a cell or range update the formula.  Doing a find/replace on a single cell is not addressing question.